# Best practices manual for Alienvault USM?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, scan, openvas

Is there any best practices manual for Alienvault USM?

I found some information about the profiles for the vulnerability scanner but nothing about how often I should launch the scan or which categories for a custom profile are dangerous:

- Deep - Non-destructive, full and fast scan.
- Default   - To be used when scanned system fails when overwhelmed by too many scanning requests.
- Ultimate - Full and fast scan. Includes dangerous stress tests that have potential to induce host or system failure.
- Custom profile

Which type of processes launch each profile? How often should I launch them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be answered in general because this depends on your requirements. The vulerablity scanner unitilized by Alienvaults OSSIM/USM is `OpenVAS`. So the right place to look after information about the processes launched is in the [OpenVAS documentation](http://www.openvas.org/documentation.html).

From my experience I can tell you that an extensive test will likely cause some trouble with blackbox devices. I have seen cheap switches and embeded devices (aka IOT devices) that go down even in an allegedly non harmfull scan. This is of cause a useful result of such a scan but it is of cause not very pleasant for the users. This is why I only do default scans in the week and extensive scans at the weekend. To get a realistic result I use wake on lan to start all workstations s they can be scanned even on the weekend.